# Jruby, JDBC, Netezza

Tags: java, jdbc, jruby, netezza

So anyways I have a java program like this and it totally works.

```
1 import java.sql.*;
2 import org.netezza.*;

class Conn {
 public static void main (String args []) throws SQLException {
  6         try{Class.forName ("org.netezza.Driver");
  7         }
  8         catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  9             System.out.println("You made it to here");
 10             e.printStackTrace();
 11         }
 12
 13         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:netezza://server/dbname", "user", "pass");
 14
 15         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
 16         ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 'foo'");
 17         while (rset.next()){
 18             System.out.println(rset.getString(1));
 19         }
 20         stmt.close();
 21         conn.close();
 22     }
 23 }
```

However, when I attempt to follow what seems like every vanilla JDBC + Jruby tutorial on the internet I get the ubiquitous error "NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver" with this code.

```
  1 require 'java'
  2 require 'jruby'
  3 require 'nzjdbc.jar'
  4 #F = java.io.File
  5 #class_loader = JRuby.runtime.jruby_class_loader
  6 #class_loader.add_url(F.new('path').to_url)
  7 #class_loader.add_url(F.new('nzjdbc.jar').to_url)
  8
  9 include_class "java.sql.DriverManager"
 10 include_class "org.netezza.Driver"
 11
 12 p $CLASSPATH
 13 p $LOAD_PATH
 14
 15 server = 'server'
 16 databaseName = 'dbname'
 17 user = 'user'
 18 pass = 'pass'
 19
 20 p DRVRMAN = org.netezza.Driver.new
 21
 22 begin
 23     #clazz = Java::JavaClass.for_name("org.netezza.Driver")
 24     clazz = java.lang.Class.for_name("org.netezza.Driver", true, JRuby.runtime.jruby_class_loader)
 25     #java.lang.Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(JRuby.runtime.jruby_class_loader)
 26     #java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(Java::OrgNetezza::Driver.new)
 27     url = "jdbc:netezza://" + server + "/" + databaseName
 28     p url
 29     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass)
 30     stmt = conn.create_statement
 31     rs = stmt.execute_query("SELECT 2 + 2")
 32
 33     while rs.next
 34         p [rs.get_int(1)]
 35     end
 36 ensure
 37     rs.close rescue nil
 38     stmt.close rescue nil
 39     conn.close rescue nil
 40 end
```

and I have tried what seems like everything I could find to fix this issue including checking out the activerecord-jdbc and dbi-jdbc implementations.  Its very frustrating and I guess I don't really understand whats going on besides having an issue with teh classloader, load path and the Classpath.  Anyways, I was hoping someone could explain step by step how the DriverManager registers drivers in Java and why the java code totally succeeds while the ruby code (which seems equivalent) does not as well as help me mitigate these errors.

(Also any "install X gem" won't work in this instance as a large deal of bureaucracy must be overcome for anything new to be allowed into this system)

Comment: try dropping some jars into your jruby lib dir?

Comment: I have put the jars into that lib directory in every concieveable place.  Put it on the CLASSPATH from the command line, inside the JRUBY script via the $CLASSPATH variable, via the $CLASSPATH bash env variable to no avail.

Comment: why dont you load your classes with java_import ...? not sure if that can cause your problem... i'm just wondering.

Comment: it can also mean a corrupt jar...does it work in pure java?

Comment: I have tried using java_import in place of the requires.  No help.  As for the corrupt jar, the java code above works so I suppose corrupt jar to not be the problem unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this scenario with Apache CXF. My favorite solution is to

> not waste time making jruby code work
>   and simply have a java class do that
>   for you

, which is 100% guaranteed to work. In your case, you can compile/jar your Conn class and call it from jruby like

```
Java::Conn.main()
```

Your jar can be placed in jruby/lib.

PS: I see you have tried numerous ways to make it work. 
Probably [Nick Sieger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174453/nick-sieger) can provide some insight into these class loading issues.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is what I essentially ended up doing, but I still wish I understood what was going on and what the problem is for just doing it from Jruby as theoretically it should be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't address the specific issue of using your nzjdbc.jar, I can tell you that the code you have will work with postgresql.jar, so your issue must be specific to some quirk of your driver.  I'm not sure what netezza is trying to do, but with the postgresql driver, org.postgresql.Driver has a static initialization block that simply calls javax.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver()), so simply loading that class is enough to get the driver registered.

Comment: Hmmm, the netezza driver I believe has one of those too, however it doesn't seem to load correctly.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Not much more I can say without having that driver locally.  Any tips on where to download it?  I wouldn't need to actually be able to connect to something to verify that the driver registration was handled successfully.

Comment: Hmmm, Netezza is pretty protective of their jdbc and odbc drivers.  We had to get ours from our major client (fortune 500 big deal kinda place).  We're just a small analytics/AI company and I'm trying to get jruby working because I don't really want to write all my scripts in Java since that makes my head hurt.

You can try joining, Enzee community here but I think you have to have a sales engineer contact since we haven't been able to get access to that forum either.  http://www.enzeecommunity.com/index.jspa

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails with classpath issues, I've found that putting jars in $JRUBY_HOME/lib always works.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned it, but I have tried putting it in JRUBY_HOME/lib to no avail.  Still doesn't seem to be getting picked up by the script.